# Are there any self-learning declarative/inductive programming language to input the expected results, not the procedure to follow?

Tags: language-agnostic, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, induction

The language where the computer is told what the problem is, not how to solve the problem. So given a database or a set of rules, the computer tries to find a solution matching all the desired properties.

Example 1 (format: input vars => expected output)

Set of rules:
`2, 2 => 4; 2, 4 => 6; 4, 4 => 8`, etc.

Then program learns that it needs to add all the input variables.

Comment: [Inductive logic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_logic_programming) languages can do this, at least in theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, [Inductive logic programming (ILP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_logic_programming) is a subfield of machine learning which uses [logic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_programming) as a uniform representation for examples, background knowledge and hypotheses.

In example, given an encoding of the known background knowledge and a set of examples represented as a logical database of facts, an ILP system will derive a hypothesised logic program which entails all the positive and none of the negative examples. Inductive logic programming is particularly useful in bioinformatics and natural language processing.

There are some known implementations, such as:

- [1BC and 1BC2: first-order naive Bayesian classifiers](http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/Research/MachineLearning/1BC/)
- [ACE (A Combined Engine)](http://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/ACE/)
- [Aleph](http://web.comlab.ox.ac.uk/oucl/research/areas/machlearn/Aleph/)
- [Atom](http://www.ahlgren.info/research/atom/)
- [Claudien](http://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/claudien/)
- [DL-Learner](http://dl-learner.org)
- [DMax](http://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/dmax/)
- [First Order Inductive Learner (FOIL)](ftp://ftp.cs.su.oz.au/pub/foil6.sh)
- [Golem (ILP)](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~shm/Software/golem)
- [Imparo](http://arxiv.org/abs/1407.3836)
- [Inthelex (INcremental THEory Learner from EXamples)](http://lacam.di.uniba.it:8000/systems/inthelex/)
- [Lime](http://cs.anu.edu.au/people/Eric.McCreath/lime.html)
- [Mio](http://libra.msra.cn/Publication/3392493/mio-user-s-manual)
- MIS (Model Inference System) by Ehud Shapiro
- [PROGOL](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~shm/Software/progol5.0)
- [RSD](http://labe.felk.cvut.cz/~zelezny/rsd/)
- Warmr (now included in ACE)
- [ProGolem](http://ilp.doc.ic.ac.uk/ProGolem/)